# What is the issue with my recursive algorithm through a number matrix?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, matrix, path-finding

I've spent days trying to figure out how to recursively search through a number matrix for a path that when its numbers add it, the sum must be greater than 0. The first test case kind or works, but the arrows aren't correct on the corners. But for all the other test cases, everything is not working. Do you know what's wrong with the code and what I need to do to fix it?

```
void path_finder(std::vector<std::vector<int>> & in, std::vector<std::vector<char>> & out, bool & routeFound, int & sum, char dir = 'v', int row = 0, int col = 0) {
    if (row >= in.size() || row < 0 || col >= in[row].size() || col < 0 || out[row][col] != '-' || routeFound) {
        
        return;
    } 

    if (row == in.size() -1 && col == in[row].size() - 1) {
        if (sum > 0) {
            routeFound = true;
            out[row][col] = 'X';
            return;
        } 
        return;
    }

    out[row][col] = dir;
    sum += in[row][col];

    path_finder(in, out, routeFound, sum += in[row][col], 'v', row+1, col);
    path_finder(in, out, routeFound, sum += in[row][col], '>', row, col+1);
    path_finder(in, out, routeFound, sum += in[row][col], '^', row-1, col);
    path_finder(in, out, routeFound, sum += in[row][col], '<', row, col-1);
    

}
```

Test case 1:

```
1 -10 1 -5 2
2 3 -20 2 1
-13 1 2 3 5
1 1 5 -4 4
```

Expected output:

```
v----
v----
v-->v
>>>^X
```

My output:

```
v----
v----
v--^>
v>>>X
```

Test case 2:

```
1 1 1 -5 -5 
-6 -3 -5 0 4
-5 1 2 4 0
1 0 -5 0 -4
```

Expected output:

```
> v - - -
- v - > v
- v > ^ v
- > ^ - X
```

My output:

```
v^><^
v^<v^
v<v^>
v>>>-
```

Keeping track of recursion in every direction is really hard so do you have any tips on how to solve this? The vector in takes in that matrix of integers while out is a vector full of "-" that gets replaced with arrows if a cell is part of a path.

Comment: Keeping track of recursion is not hard. You need to somehow record that a particular co-ordinate is currently on the recursion stack. This is a fundamental of recursion. Before you make your recursive calls, check that the position is not marked. If it is, return immediately. Otherwise mark it, do your recursive calls, and unmark it before returning. Otherwise you'll find that your recursion allows you to travel in circles until you overflow the stack. It actually looks like you're partially doing this already, except that you don't handle the "not-found" case (set `out[row][col] = '-'` again)

Comment: A 5x5 matrix strikes me as a bit large for debugging ease. Can you come up with a 3x3 or maybe even 2x2 example that demonstrates the problem? Top-left corner to bottom-right by way of the bottom-left corner? You don't need more than 2x2 to have that sort of path.

Answer (score 0):

It has been many many years since I looked a C/C++ so I am bit rusty!  Apologies in advance if I have got anything wrong.

However, it seems to me that you are not checking all the boundary conditions for the recursion.  Also, you only give one solution for your test cases.  If I understand the problem context correctly, while any level of the recursion will only have one in, there can be multiple outs, ie, there are multiple solutions for a path with total greater than zero for both matrices starting at the top left and finishing at the bottom right.  Are you overwriting and getting a chaotic blend of multiple solutions?  Your out should be a vector of vector of vector?  And, why is 'v' treated specially?

Below is a solution in python, which finds all solutions, total greater than zero, from top left to bottom right. The are some obvious similarities to parts of your code.

If you want me to convert this into C/C++, it will no doubt take me a several days (since it has been a very very long time ...).

```
matrices = [

[
[ 1, -10, 1, -5, 2 ],
[ 2, 3, -20, 2, 1 ],
[ -13, 1, 2, 3, 5 ],
[ 1, 1, 5, -4, 4 ]
],

[
[ 1, 1, 1, -5, -5 ],
[ -6, -3, -5, 0, 4 ],
[ -5, 1, 2, 4, 0 ],
[ 1, 0, -5, 0, -4]
]

]

def findPaths(matrix):

    X = len(matrix)
    Y = len(matrix[0])
                
    def buildPaths(startX, startY, path, steps):
        if startX == X - 1 and startY == Y - 1:
            total = 0
            for node in path:
                total += matrix[node[0]][node[1]]
            total += matrix[startX][startY]
            if total > 0:
                return [ [ True, [ *path, (startX, startY) ], total, [ *steps, "x" ] ] ]
            else:
                return [ [ False ] ]
        if startX < 0 or startX == X or startY < 0 or startY == Y:
            return [ [ False ] ]
        snookered = True
        paths = []
        if ( (startX-1, startY) ) not in path:
            snookered = False
            paths +=  buildPaths( startX-1, startY, [ *path, (startX, startY) ], [ *steps, "^" ] )
        if ( (startX, startY-1) ) not in path:
            snookered = False
            paths +=  buildPaths( startX, startY-1, [ *path, (startX, startY) ], [ *steps, "<" ] )
        if ( (startX, startY+1) ) not in path:
            snookered = False
            paths +=  buildPaths( startX, startY+1, [ *path, (startX, startY) ], [ *steps, ">" ] )
        if ( (startX+1, startY) ) not in path:
            snookered = False
            paths +=  buildPaths( startX+1, startY, [ *path, (startX, startY) ], [ *steps, "v" ] )
        if snookered:
            return [ [ False ] ]
        return paths

    paths = buildPaths( 0, 0, [], [] )
    print( len(paths) )

    for path in paths:
        if path[0]:
            steps = ""
            for x in range(0, X):
                steps += "\n"
                for y in range(0, Y):
                    try:
                        step = path[1].index( (x, y) )
                    except ValueError:
                        steps += "-"
                    else:
                        steps += path[3][step]
            print(steps)
            print(path[2])

for matrix in matrices:
    findPaths(matrix)
```